# How to create Flutter Table?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, datagrid, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to create a table the same as in this one  :

[image]

Is there an easy way to show the author's books the way they appear in the table above?.

I tried to use a List of ExpansionTile, but the code become more complicated
since i want to fetch the data from an API.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid

Answer (score 1):

1. First, we need to add a Table widget in the body.
2. Next, we have to add TableRow(s) in children of the table widget. Since the table widget has multiple rows, so we use children, not child.
3. Finally, we need to add TableCell(s) in children of TableRow widget. Now, we can write any widget in this place like we are going to use a Text widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  
  
void main() {runApp(MyApp());}  
  
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {  
  @override  
  _TableExample createState() => _TableExample();  
}  
  
class _TableExample extends State<MyApp> {  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return MaterialApp(  
      home: Scaffold(  
          appBar: AppBar(  
            title: Text('Flutter Table Example'),  
          ),  
          body: Center(  
              child: Column(children: <Widget>[  
                Container(  
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),  
                  child: Table(  
                    defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(120.0),  
                    border: TableBorder.all(  
                        color: Colors.black,  
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,  
                        width: 2),  
                    children: [  
                      TableRow( children: [  
                        Column(children:[Text('Website', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('Tutorial', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('Review', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))]),  
                      ]),  
                      TableRow( children: [  
                        Column(children:[Text('Javatpoint')]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('Flutter')]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('5*')]),  
                      ]),  
                      TableRow( children: [  
                        Column(children:[Text('Javatpoint')]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('MySQL')]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('5*')]),  
                      ]),  
                      TableRow( children: [  
                        Column(children:[Text('Javatpoint')]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('ReactJS')]),  
                        Column(children:[Text('5*')]),  
                      ]),  
                    ],  
                  ),  
                ),  
              ])  
          )),  
    );  
  }  
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what i meant is : lets say we have authors and each author has his own books, now i want to create a table that have group of authors and under each author his books (like tree). as shown in the pic